# Помогите решить задачу в SQL

Tags: sql

Не могу понять как посчитать страницы в этом задании [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В вашем скриншоте не видно полностью таблицу исходную

Comment: таблица там просто для примера, в моем решении  в итоге не сгруппированы страницы за один год, должно быть общее колличество страниц и год не должен повторятся в таблице дважды

Answer (score 1):

Следует сгруппировать по годам, суммируя количество страниц

```sql
SELECT publish_year as `year`, SUM(number_of_pages) as `number_of_pages`
FROM book
WHERE publish_year BETWEEN 2011 AND 2015
GROUP BY publish_year 
ORDER BY `year` DESC;
```

В зависимости от используемого диалекта SQL кавычки в названиях алиасов могут отличаться.

Comment: Спасибо, неправильно группировал по страницам а не по году выпуска!